# What does a Firebase observer actually do?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say this observer is created when the app is launched

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // do something
})
```

What is going on behind the scenes? How does the app know when the value changes? All I can imagine is this

```
while (true) {
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // if value is different do something
    })
}
```

Comment: How do you define 'cost' and why include a function if it's never called? You may want to expand your question with a use case and more data (code) or else it may be closed for being to vague.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Jay. I'm wondering how a Firebase observer works. What is the code behind the observe function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Firebase client keeps an open socket connection to its backend server. When you attach the observer, it sends that information to the server, which will from then on track the observed location. The server also sends back the current value (or lack thereof) on the location. The client will immediately fire/invoke your completion block with that value.

After this initial flow, whenever the value at the location changes, the Firebase server sends an update to the client over the open socket. When the client receives such an update, it invokes the completion block again with the updated value (or lack thereof).