# Observe multiple children of same node in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Realtime Database to resolve the user's uid to a temporal peerId. Each user creates this peerId when they are going online and sets them to null, before they go offline.
Thus a user is online, if their uid is found in /peerIdByUid/.

This is how my data looks:

```
/peerIdByUid/$uid = $peerId
```

Each user is a node with its uid as key and peerId as value.

Each user has friends and needs to know, if they are online, going offline, etc.

Do I need to create an observer for each reference?

Example:

```
//for each friend
firebase.database().ref('/peerIdByUid/' + friendUserId).on('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  //display friend online/offline
});
```

Is there a more elegant solution, where I observe only the user's friends with one observer?

And I do not want to do something expensive like:

```
firebase.database().ref('/peerIdByUid').on("value")...
```

Because this would download the data for all users to the client and probably bankrupt me.

I am thinking of something like

```
const refsToFriends = ['/peerIdByUid/firend1', '/peerIdByUid/friend2', ...];
firebase.database().observe(refToFriend).on('value').then(...);
```

On the other hand, according to this answer: [What does a Firebase observer actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843555/what-does-a-firebase-observer-actually-do) it would not make sense, and I can just create an observer on each friend's reference.

I also thought about writing the peerIds in each user's friendlist. But this would multiply the amount of needed space and traffic by the number of each friend. And the peerId changes very frequently. So I want it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I went with observing each friends peerId with an observer, but stored each observer into a Dictionary to prevent multiple observers for one person. I also found this: [Enabling Offline Capabilities in JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities)

**onDisconnect**:
`onDisconnect()` triggers an operation, when a client disconnects from the database. If the browser crashes, the unload event (which I used) is not fired, but `onDisconnect()` will be.

Register peerId and delete it on disconnect:

```
//this function registers the peerId to the uid and saves the current timstamp
//it also deletes the peerId and timestamp on disconnect
async registerPeerId(uid: string, peerId: string) {
    const peerIdRef = firebase.database.ref(`peerIdByUid/${uid}`);
    await peerIdRef.set({
        peerId,
        timestamp: db.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    });
    peerIdRef.onDisconnect().set(null);
}
```

Listen to friends going on- and offline:

```
//global dictionary to store observer for friends
const friendListeners: Dictionary<Function> = {}; 
// some function to that is called on initalization of app
async function loadFriends(){
  const friends = await findFriends(); //load friends
  await Promise.all(friends.map(async (f: Friend) => {
    listenToFriend(f);
    // other stuff: e.g. connecting to friend
  });
}

function listenToFriend(friend: Friend) {
  //check if an observer exists
  if(!(friend.uid in friendListeners)) {
    friendListeners[friend.uid] = firebase.database
                                  .ref(`peerIdByUid/${friend.uid}`)
                                  .on("value", (snapshot: db.DataSnapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        let {peerId} = snapshot.val();
        //this stores the new peerId into a global store that can be checked fast and cheap
        upsertPeerId(friend.uid, peerId);
      } else {
        // sets peerId to null to show that user is offline
        upsertPeerId(friend.uid, null);
      }
    });
  }
}
```